# Comparing two ArrayLists efficiently

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have been asked to do this:

Write function scramble(str1,str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false.

For example:
str1 is 'rkqodlw' and str2 is 'world' the output should return true.
str1 is 'cedewaraaossoqqyt' and str2 is 'codewars' should return true.
str1 is 'katas' and str2 is 'steak' should return false.

Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
Performance needs to be considered

My code is this:

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scramblies {

```
static ArrayList<String> strTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> strOne = new ArrayList<String>();
static String sub1;
static String sub2; 

public static void main (String[] args){

}

public static boolean scramble(String str1, String str2) {
boolean can = false;
int str1length = str1.length();
int looping = 0;
int counter = 0;

    //put str1 into arraylist strOne
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
        sub1 = str1.substring(i);
        for (int k = 0; k<str1.length(); k++){
            strOne.add(k, sub1);
        }
    }

    //Put str2 into arraylist strTwo
    for (int i = 0; i< str2.length(); i++){
        sub2 = str2.substring(i);
        for (int k = 0; k < str2.length(); k++){
        strTwo.add(k,sub2);
        }

    }

    //now search for str1 in the array strTwo. While loop so that it keeps looping the first for statement
   while (looping != str1.length()){

       for (int x = 0; x < strOne.size(); x++) {
           looping++;
            if(strTwo.contains(strOne.get(x))) {
                  counter++;
             }
       }        
   }





   if (counter == str2.length()){  //check the counter against the length of str1 (int str1length) and if they are the same then can = true
       can = true;
   } else {
       can = false;
   }



    return can;
}
```

}

My question is: does this code work and - if so - how can it be made more efficient. I think this concept works, but it's lack of elegance is causing me to fail the time limitations on compiling and executing the code in code wars.

UPDATE:

Based on some of the comments I have updated the code and this works perfectly. However the question of efficiency still remains. Here is the code:

public class Scramblies {

```
public static boolean scramble(String str1, String str2) {
    String temp = str1;
    int count = 0;
    boolean result = true;
    for(int i=0 ; i<str2.length() ; i++){
        char c = str2.charAt(i);
        if(temp.contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            temp = temp.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(c), "");
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == str2.length()){
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

If anyone can assist me in making this code more efficient so it doesn't time out when running against the efficiency portion of the test, that would be great. I am also posted it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/comparing-two-strings-to-see-if-string-2-is-inside-string-1

Comment: Sort both arrays of characters; if the second contains all of the first then they match.

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what's the problem? If so, what's your question?

Comment: won't work if the larger string has multiple occurrences of the same letter where the subset only has one, a straight String.compare() won't work then.

Comment: Your method seems wrong. When you add the substring into to arraylist, the next adding step will overlap the former step.

Comment: _"My question is: does this code work"_ well, test it! _"how can it be made more efficient"_ is better asked on CodeReview.

Comment: *"how can it be made more efficient?"* is only asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) after the first question has been answered with a "Yes".  (I'm not suggesting the question is on-topic for [so], just that without the answer to whether or not the code works, the question is off-topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method which iterates through each character of `String` s2 and checks whether it's present in `s1`, simultaneously removing the matches occurrence form s1, e.g.:

```
private static boolean canScramble(String s1, String s2){
    String temp = s1;
    boolean result = true;
    for(int i=0 ; i<s2.length() ; i++){
        char c = s2.charAt(i);
        if(temp.contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            temp = temp.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(c), "");
        }else{
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would work, but very inefficient because of all the new strings that are created.

Comment: Not really, strings will be used from String pool.

Comment: Hi Darshan, I looked over your code and it sort of worked. I think you failed to grasp exactly what it is I was supposed to be doing, but I was able to modify your code based on the fact that you demonstrated how to use some new methods in the String class that I was unfamiliar with. While your solution wasn't an answer to the question, it helped me more than any other responses, so I will give it a tick for the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Also my new code needs to be more efficient. So Scott's comment on this is perfectly right. I will post the finished code once completed.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of integers, large enough to hold all possible characters (26 for English), and initialize to 0.

For each character in the large string, get the current integer and increment by 1.  This represents all possible characters that could be rearranged.

For each character in the small string, get the current integer value and decrement by 1.  If at any point, the updated value is -1, the larger string cannot be rearranged.

As an aside, for performance reasons you might consider working a raw character buffer rather than substring or pulling individual characters out.

Comment: It's not clear from the answer if you must use ArrayLists, but if not I'd use a Map for counting characters.

Comment: could you elaborate on this a little? I am relatively new to java. What do you mean by this: "For each character in the large string, get the current integer and increment by 1. This represents all possible characters that could be rearranged."

Comment: The concept would be the same in any programming language: create an array of integers with a size of 26...for any character 'a' you see increment array[0], for any character 'b' increment array[1], etc. and by the time you examine each character in the large string you've figured out the character distribution.

Comment: Scott, so would I add all 26 values to the Array? I don't really know what you mean by initialising the array to 0. Would you mind providing some example code for me to follow? It would really help. Thanks.

Comment: int[26] values; for (int a = 0; a < 26; a++) values[a] = 0;